# Why do I get an empty folder when I publish with Web Deploy

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, web-deployment, publish

I recently tried publishing my asp.net project (.NET Framework 4.6.1) to a network location with web deploy. The project builds as expected, but when it gets to "Publishing folder /..." it just continues without a delay and ends successfully ("Web App was published successfully"), while not actually publishing anything. The target folder is still empty afterwards. Publishing to a local file system didn't work either. When I checked the option "Delete all existing files prior to publish" it deleted the files in the folder. This suggests, that the target folder is accessible. Some weeks ago it have worked with the same publishing profile.

publishing profile:

```
  <Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <WebPublishMethod>FileSystem</WebPublishMethod>
    <LastUsedBuildConfiguration>Test</LastUsedBuildConfiguration>
    <LastUsedPlatform>Any CPU</LastUsedPlatform>
    <SiteUrlToLaunchAfterPublish />
    <LaunchSiteAfterPublish>True</LaunchSiteAfterPublish>
    <ExcludeApp_Data>False</ExcludeApp_Data>
    <publishUrl>\\myserver\project\wwwroot</publishUrl>
    <DeleteExistingFiles>False</DeleteExistingFiles>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

Comment: when you click on publish you will get the publish window check click on **Target location path** you will redirect to exact where exactly is going to published

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The target folder is the correct one, but it's still empty.